# System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.EnvelopedCms.GetCspParams return exception "Cannot find object or property."

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, x509certificate

I have exception while try to decrypt file :

```
           var encData = File.ReadAllBytes(encFile);

           var file = File.ReadAllBytes(encFile);
        
           ContentInfo cinf = new ContentInfo(file);

           var ec = new EnvelopedCms(cinf);

           X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
           store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

           ec.Decode(encData);

           ec.Decrypt(store.Certificates);
```

I exactly know that inside List `store.Certificates` proper sertificate exsists, why thrown exception ?
This code have worked before I add that new certificate, with no difference from previous except hash algorithm ...

UPD: full call stack exception is

```
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.EnvelopedCms.GetCspParams(RecipientInfo recipientInfo, X509Certificate2Collection extraStore, CMSG_DECRYPT_PARAM& cmsgDecryptParam)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.EnvelopedCms.DecryptContent(RecipientInfoCollection recipientInfos, X509Certificate2Collection extraStore)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.EnvelopedCms.Decrypt(X509Certificate2Collection extraStore)
```

Comment: GetCspParams returned an exception? You're not calling that anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks - I add full call stack exception - it call from Decrypt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this exception - not supported hash algorithm - defined in russian standard GOST R 34.11-2012 or STREEBOG. So because I have CryptoPro licence I use cryptcp.exe with command line parameters ...